# Change a datetime to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the number of days between two dates and output it as a string.

Here is what I have

```
currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()
newDate = currentDate + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
dateDifference = newDate - currentDate
print(dateDifference)
```

I've tried

```
print(dateDifference.strftime('%d'))
```

But this doesn't work.

I want the out to say only the number "3" as a string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the day difference as a string you can do

```
print(str(dateDifference.days))
```

Comment: There is no `string` function, even in Python 3.

Comment: There is `str` though, sorry got 2.7 and 3.x backwards

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
>>> print(dateDifference.days)
3
```

Or if you want a string, you can do the below code, as per @BenT took the solution using `str`, which is preferred (you should use that), I would give a solution with string formatting:

```
>>> print('%s' % dateDifference.days)
3
>>> type('%s' % dateDifference.days)
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: This returns an `int` value and not a string which is what the author wants.

Comment: @BenT: If you're going to be printing it, you don't need to call `str` manually. `print` will do that for you.

Comment: Yes but I am assuming that printing the value is not the final product that the poster is using this for.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

currentDate = datetime.now()
newDate = currentDate + timedelta(days=3)
dateDifference = str(newDate - currentDate)
print(type(dateDifference))
print(dateDifference)
```

### OUTPUT

```
<class 'str'>
3 days, 0:00:00
>>>
```